# MySQL create trigger after insert not inserting all values

Tags: mysql, trigger

I am new to MySQL triggers. i want to insert the newly inserted booking from booking table to bookings_clone table.

**PROBLEM:**

All the field in bookings table are filled but in bookings_clone only these fields are getting inserted (id, uniqueid, branch_id, user_id, status, sms_status, email_status, created_at, updated_at) and rest of them are null. Any help in pointing me to right direction is highly appreciated. The table structure of bookings_clone is same as bookings.

**CREATE TRIGGER:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_booking_insert
AFTER INSERT ON bookings
FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO bookings_clone
(id, unique_id, branch_id, pos_user_id, user_id,
 user_address_id, address, postcode, city, town,
 status, order_due_date, order_due_time,
 checkout_mode, sms_status, email_status, notes,
 time_taken, accepted_at, delivery_charges,
 discount_amount, total_charges, sub_total_charges,
 initiator, created_at, updated_at, deleted_at)
 VALUES
 (NEW.id, NEW.unique_id, NEW.branch_id, NEW.pos_user_id, NEW.user_id,
 NEW.user_address_id, NEW.address, NEW.postcode, NEW.city, NEW.town,
 NEW.status, NEW.order_due_date, NEW.order_due_time,
 NEW.checkout_mode, NEW.sms_status, NEW.email_status, NEW.notes,
 NEW.time_taken, NEW.accepted_at, NEW.delivery_charges,
 NEW.discount_amount, NEW.total_charges, NEW.sub_total_charges,
 NEW.initiator, NEW.created_at, NEW.updated_at, NEW.deleted_at);
```

I've also tried this but the result is same

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER after_booking_inserted AFTER INSERT ON bookings
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN  
    INSERT INTO bookings_clone select * from bookings where id = NEW.id;
END;//
DELIMITER ;
```

**Bookings Table Structure:**

[image]

Comment: You are trying to _produce_ `NULLs`?  Or _avoid_ `NULLs`?  Please provide an `INSERT` that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I'm trying to copy the last inserted row from bookings to bookings_clone

Comment: only these fields data is inserted into bookings_clone (id, uniqueid, branch_id, user_id, status, sms_status, email_status, created_at, updated_at) I even switched from mysql 5.7 to mariadb 10.4 but the result is same. i cannot seem to firgure out why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reprocuce your behaviour.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE bookings(ID int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,unique_id int, branch_id int, pos_user_id int, user_id int, user_address_id  int)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE bookings_clone(ID int ,unique_id int, branch_id int, pos_user_id int, user_id int, user_address_id  int)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER after_booking_inserted AFTER INSERT ON bookings
> FOR EACH ROW BEGIN  
>     INSERT INTO bookings_clone select * from bookings where id = NEW.id;
> END;
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO bookings  VALUES(NULL,13,13,13,13,13)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM bookings_clone
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | unique_id | branch_id | pos_user_id | user_id | user_address_id
> -: | --------: | --------: | ----------: | ------: | --------------:
>  1 |        13 |        13 |          13 |      13 |              13
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b4df44936d83cea7ef075dd8ce9781f2)*

So as long  as you don't have a [mre] without images, you should check if the tables arethe same.

Comment: I checked out dbfiddle, when i changed the DB to MySQL 5.7 it does not work.

Comment: @Wcan, nothing seems to work for 5.7 at db<>fiddle at the moment, it works with 5.6

Comment: @Wcan here is another fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3woAVSw5hrav15jAmuWVdT/7

Comment: The problem was not in trigger, both triggers were working as they were supposed to, some where in code an update statement was called on bookings, the initial insert was inserting exactly the same data which i mentioned above but then the update statement was putting more data in it.